# Align top to the large label using autolayout

Tags: uitableview, autolayout

I Have two label in a UITableViewCell, one is on left and one is on right.
Height of both the label could be different , if label 1 is of more height than label 2 , An icon top would be label1.bottom+30 . If label 2 is of more height than label 1 then icon.top = label2.bottom+30. How to set the constraint. 
I am trying to use inequality constraints but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want your icon to be `30` below the lower of the two labels.  The trick is to use an inequality constraint and to set different priorities.

1. Set icon.top = label1.bottom + 30.  Give this constraint a priority lower than 1000.
2. Set icon.top >= label2.bottom + 30.  Leave this with the default priority of 1000.

Then if the bottom of label1 is lower, the icon will stay `30` from it because both constraints can be satisfied.  If the bottom of label2 is lower, *Auto Layout* will break the lower priority constraint to keep the icon `30` away from label2.  Although it breaks the constraint making the icon `30` below label1, it keeps the value as close to `30` as it can.

---

Here is a demo:

The slider changes the height of RedView.  The key constraints are:

1. BlueView.top >= GreenView.bottom + 30
2. BlueView.top = RedView.bottom + 30 @ Priority 999

[image: Demo in a simulator]